# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not called anymore

Tags: android

For a very simple app to send data to an API, I decided to use the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener to set up the UI based on the authentication status. I either show the authentication fragment or the sending fragment and switch when the *status* changes:

Listener registration:

```
val sharedPreferences = this.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(ApplicationConstants.sharedPreferencesKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

if (!sharedPreferences.contains(ApplicationConstants.authTokenPreferenceKey))
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(ApplicationConstants.authTokenPreferenceKey, null).apply()

// change fragment based on shared preference value (login status)
sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { sp, key ->
        if (!key.equals(ApplicationConstants.authTokenPreferenceKey))
            return@registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

        if (sp.getString(key, null) == null) {
            // goto identity fragment if no already there
            if (!this.isCurrentFragmentOfTag(IdentityFragment::class.java.name))
                this.replaceFragment(IdentityFragment())
        } else {
            // goto tracking fragment if not already there
            if (!this.isCurrentFragmentOfTag(TrackingFragment::class.java.name))
                this.replaceFragment(TrackingFragment())
        }
    }

if (sharedPreferences.getString(ApplicationConstants.authTokenPreferenceKey, null) == null)
    this.replaceFragment(IdentityFragment())
else
    this.replaceFragment(TrackingFragment())
```

Setting the *status* when authenticated:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    try {
        val response = RetrofitInstance.api.sendLoginRequest(LoginRequest(usernameEmail, password))
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { // was just a try if that's the reason. Dont know if necessary
                view.context.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(ApplicationConstants.sharedPreferencesKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .edit().putString(ApplicationConstants.authTokenPreferenceKey, "Bearer " + response.body()?.token)
                    .apply()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(view.context, "Login up error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(view.context, "Login up error: " + e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

deleting the *status* to log out:

```
textViewLogout.setOnClickListener {
    view.context.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(ApplicationConstants.sharedPreferencesKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        .edit().putString(ApplicationConstants.authTokenPreferenceKey, null).apply()
}
```

The value changes all the time, but the listener is not called. When I close the app and reopen the other fragment is displayed.